# Add/edit combo box type field on Magento 2 admin form

Tags: magento2, adminform, ui-select

I need to add a select box with a text box so if any data present then admin can select else can type at the same time like below:

[image]

[image]

plus(+) symbol will override select box to a textbox.

Comment: where you want like this type fields?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, I want this in product module (admin panel)

Comment: means in backend where? in system config side? or product view side?

Comment: @RakeshDonga, Product view add/edit fom, not in config

Comment: i think that was not possible

Comment: @RakeshDonga, We have done this in M1 via JS